# Introduce contente of several files into SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I listed the files of a directory in my computer, then I append them into a list. Then I created a pandas dataframe, with the content of those files... However, when I insert those dataframe into sql, I only got the last file of the list.
Here is the code that I'm using:

```
files_in_folder=[]
directory=r'C:\Users\-\Documents'
network_directory=os.listdir(directory)
filepaths = [os.path.join(directory, filename) for filename in network_directory ]
fastq_directory={}
newest = max(filepaths, key=lambda x: os.stat(x).st_mtime)
file_path_list=[]
for file in os.listdir(newest):
    file_path=newest+"\\"+ file
    file_path_list.append(file_path)
while file_path_list:
    left_files=file_path_list.pop(0)
    if left_files.endswith('.???'):
        ordered_fastq=convert_files(left_files) 
        type_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(ordered_fastq.items(), columns=['ID', 'Ref'])
```

When I print the content of the dataframe I get this:

```
     ID   ... Ref
0      >927  ...   aaa
1      >931  ...   aab

...  ...  ...    ...

[32334 rows x 4 columns]
        ID   ... Ref
0      >942  ...   bdc
1      >951  ...   bde

...    ...  ...    ...

[124030 rows x 4 columns]
          ID  ... Ref
0       >958  ...   ftp
1       >448  ...   l_d
...      ...  ...    ...
```

Its seems that I have a huge dataframe with other dataframes... Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might help to try to see what happens when you work with one or two files. Instead of starting with your whole computer, create a new directory with two text files and try to work from there. Some code that seems confusing to me is `for file in os.listdir(newest):`, There is probably a simpler way to get the file paths of all of your files (os has a good method)

Comment: I'm already working in a directory with only 3 files...